# Hard disk doesnt show up after a failed ubuntu minimal installation!

Tags: boot

I had windows 8 & I downloaded ubuntu minimal,burned to dvd and booted and started the installation and gone through partition and all those things and while setup was downloading installation files light went off and I have to stop the setup then rebooted and nothing happens windows 8 vanished and no hard disk is detected! !

Any help please

Comment: Where exactly does it say "hard disk not detected"? Could you run off a Live CD and check if your hard drive is detected (run `Disks` from the Dash)? If it's not, you have hardware issues. If it is, you can just restart the installation, can't you?

Comment: I tried installing new copy of windows 8 it doesn't shows up any hdd while on disk selector menu

Comment: Sounds like a hardware issue then. Perhaps your hard drive died? Those things happen now and then, especially when hitting them with a lot of I/O during OS installation. Again, check your hard drive status and health in "Disks" run from the Ubuntu live CD.

Comment: when i try installing windows 8 from windows 8 setup the windows files can be seen on x:\ drive while browsing

Answer (score 0):

i think its because you did'nt complete the installation. when the backlight was off, installation was running backward, you ejected the installtion media and aborted installation. do it again and completely. restart your computer when it commands you, not before.

Comment: When I try again installing the windows at booting the cd on the disk selection part it doesn't shows any hard drives my hdd is hitachi 500 G

Comment: i suggested you to install ubuntu again. i cannot say without seeing. in think your hard disk crushed. boot ubuntu in live medium and open the gparted software. it will show you your hard disk's partitions. if anything happens then resize hard disk and try installing again. create ntfs partition for windows.